# In R, when transpose data from row to column, why spread() code doesn't work?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, reshape, transpose

I have a data below

```
dataA= data.frame(
  Location = rep(c("East", "West", "North"), each = 12 * 2),
  Season = rep(rep(c(2021, 2022), each = 6), 3),
  Genotype = rep(rep(c("CV1", "CV2"), each = 6), 3),
  Iron_ton_ha = rep(c(21.7127, 16.9369, 30.7798, 14.0833, 13.2023, 11.1327, 15.0424, 
                      9.6616, 5.8569, 6.1881, 8.0127, 6.0291), each = 6),
  Stage = rep(c("Vegetative", "Reproductive", "Maturity"), each = 12),
  Fe = rep(c(0.44, 0.36, 0.31, 0.28, 0.79, 0.38, 0.59, 0.35, 0.41, 0.4, 0.29, 0.27,
             0.37, 0.3, 0.31, 0.28, 0.16, 0.24, 0.57, 0.27, 0.23, 0.26, 0.26, 0.27,
             0.13, 0.15, 0.04, 0.06, 0.03, 0.23, 0.52, 0.06, 0.08, 0.11, 0.1, 0.04), 
           each = 2)
)
```

and I want to move each variable within the Stage column to each column, and I used the below code. But some data is missing, showing NA. Could you tell me why it does not work?

Thanks,

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

dataB= dataA %>%
  group_by(Location, Season, Genotype, Iron_ton_ha, Stage) %>%
  summarise(Fe = mean(Fe, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  spread(key = Stage, value = Fe)

dataB

# A tibble: 12 × 7
# Groups:   Location, Season, Genotype, Iron_ton_ha [12]
   Location Season Genotype Iron_ton_ha Maturity Reproductive Vegetative
   <chr>     <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>    <dbl>        <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 East       2021 CV1            21.7   NA            NA          0.37 
 2 East       2021 CV1            30.8   NA             0.45      NA    
 3 East       2022 CV2            14.1   NA             0.32      NA    
 4 East       2022 CV2            16.9   NA            NA          0.483
 5 North      2021 CV1             5.86  NA             0.107     NA    
 6 North      2021 CV1             8.01   0.22         NA         NA    
 7 North      2022 CV2             6.03   0.0833       NA         NA    
 8 North      2022 CV2             6.19  NA             0.107     NA    
 9 West       2021 CV1            13.2    0.327        NA         NA    
10 West       2021 CV1            15.0   NA            NA          0.357
11 West       2022 CV2             9.66  NA            NA          0.263
12 West       2022 CV2            11.1    0.227        NA         NA
```

Comment: `spread` works fine. The issue is that all combos which are not present in your data get assigned a missing value, e.g. for "East", "2021", "CV1", "21.7". there is only a value for stage "Vegetative". Hence, for this combo Maturity and Reproductive get assigned an NA.

Comment: @stefan thank you for your comment. I made a mistake when generating data. Actually AI generated. Now I realized I should not trust AI. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Also, `spread` is deprecated in favor of `pivot_wider`

Comment: @mhovd Thank you!! Could you please write the code using pivot_wider?

Comment: Using `pivot_wider`: ``dataA |> 
  group_by(Location, Season, Genotype, Iron_ton_ha, Stage) |> 
  summarise(Fe = mean(Fe, na.rm = TRUE)) |> 
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = c(Location, Season, Genotype, Iron_ton_ha), 
    names_from = Stage,
    values_from = Fe
  )``

Comment: @nightstand Thank you so much!! I solved the problem and understood the code. Thanks!!

Comment: @nightstand post it as an answer! :-)